# My vim ui is weird. It is hard to explain in word, please see the picture

Tags: vim

Help! My vim ui is weird. It is hard to explain in word, please see the picture.

[image: my vim weird ui]

Comment: Are you running it in tmux?

Comment: Any chance you have `hlsearch` set? Try `set nohlsarch`

Comment: @Ry-♦  Yes. But it also appears when it not in tmux.

Comment: @Thor I tried. But it still appears.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? Have you tried with others?

Comment: @Ry-♦  My vim in wsl.exe has this problem.  But my vim is ok  when I am in mobaxterm to open the wsl shell.   So it is the  wsl.exe config problem

Comment: looks like it's in diff mode - try :diffoff

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the search register:

```
:let @/=""
```

I have some mapping to temporarelly disable hlsearch, actually it toggles it, wich is more convinient, in my humble opinion.

```
nnoremap <silent> <c-l> <ESC>:set hls! hls?<cr> :call clearmatches()<cr><left><c-l>
inoremap <silent> <c-l> <C-o>:set hls! hls?<cr> <C-o>:call clearmatches()<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <c-l> <ESC>:set hls! hls?<cr> <bar> gv :call clearmatches()<cr>
```